# Finding day of the week in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

`to_char(sysdate,'Day')` returns the current day of the week. What I want is to get the `date` of the most recent "sunday" that passed. Of course we can go for a complex query to get it done. But is there any simple way I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE-8, 'SUN') FROM DUAL;
```

here

```
SYSDATE-8
```

returns the day before 8 days &

```
NEXT_DAY(mydate, 'SUN')
```

returns the next sunday to it

Comment: Actually my question is Isn't there something like `Previous_day`?

Comment: but it is required as we find the next day

Comment: @zandr According to this documentation [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm) there no such function like **Previous_day**

Comment: I think your query would fail to return `sysdate` in case current day itself is sunday.

Comment: @zander if you want to count the `sysdate` in resent days you shoud go for `NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE-7, 'SUN')` insted of `NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE-6, 'SUN')`

Comment: @zander as you have asked **most recent "sunday" that passed.** i have taken `SYSDATE-8` as current `SYSDATE` is not passed yet..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a query as simple as this:

```
SELECT dt
  FROM ( SELECT SYSDATE - LEVEL - 1 dt
           FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 8)
 WHERE TO_CHAR ( dt, 'd' ) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE-6, 'SUN')` would work. Assuming current day as sunday, I go back 6 days (i.e. last monday) and so when I look for the next sunday, I'd get the `sysdate` itself. Whereas, `next_day(sysdate-8,'SUN')` could be used to get the last day of previous week. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dt
  FROM ( SELECT to_date('5/23/2014') - LEVEL + 1 dt
           FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 8)
 WHERE TO_CHAR ( dt, 'd' ) = 1
```

I changed `LEVEL - 1 dt` to `LEVEL + 1 dt` to get it to work to find the previous Sunday.