# oracle sql get last Sunday and last Saturday

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I will calculate last Sunday and last Saturday on every Monday.

E.g. today is 08 July 2013 Monday

last Sunday: 30 June 2013 00:00:00

last Saturday: 6 July 2013 23:59:59.

Note the last Sunday is from 00:00:00 and last Saturday is until 23:59:59

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding day of the week in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815968/finding-day-of-the-week-in-oracle)

Comment: Why is "the last sunday" a week ago and the last staturday the day before yesterday. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's because here (this company) it is Sunday the first day of a week, and Saturday the last day of a week. So on a Monday, which is actually second day of a week. So 'last Sunday' and 'last Saturday' will be 5 days apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your question, where the query will be run only on Mondays and the objective is to obtain the dates as stated above, one way to solve it is:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS TODAYS_DATE,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE)-8 AS PREVIOUS_SUNDAY,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) - (INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AS PREVIOUS_SATURDAY
  FROM DUAL
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 13):

For those looking to get the last weekend days (Saturday and Sunday) on week where the first day is Monday, here's an alternative:

```
select today as todays_date,
       next_day(today - 7, 'sat') as prev_saturday, 
       next_day(today - 7, 'sun') as prev_sunday
from dual
```

Comment: Our Oracle didn't like 'today' so I substituted 'sysdate' and got the expected result - thanks for teaching me about the 'next_day' function!

Answer (score 8):

Query for get last SUNDAY :

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)-(select to_char(sysdate-1, 'd') FROM DUAL) FROM DUAL
```

Query for get last SATURDAY :

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual) FROM DUAL
```

If you want get previous SUNDAY/SATURDAY you need add to the sysdate - for example :

Previous Sunday:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd')+6 FROM DUAL) FROM DUAL
```

Previous Saturday:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd')+7 FROM DUAL) FROM DUAL
```

**The advantage of this approach is that you can do this query each day of the week** enjoy

Comment: Good one. But the LAST SUNDAY must be with `to_number(to_char(sysdate-1,'d')`, LAST SATURDAY with `to_number(to_char(sysdate,'d')`

Comment: it give previous Sunday if I run it on Sunday.

Comment: The nested dual isn't necessary. it could be,  as noted below, SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)- to_char(sysdate-1, 'd') FROM DUAL for sunday and similar for saturday.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the quickest way to get the last Saturday or last Sunday from **ANY** day of the week:

Last Saturday:

```
select trunc(SYSDATE) - to_char(sysdate, 'd')  from dual;
```

Last Sunday:

```
select trunc(SYSDATE) - (to_char(sysdate, 'd')-1)  from dual;
```

Apologies for taking 6 years to give you the best answer. ;)

Comment: Of note: the formula has to be adjusted depending on your locale, when the week start is on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

This will be more useful. You can take Last Saturday or Sunday from any given day(Not only Monday) by using the query below.

```
select NEXT_DAY(sysdate-7, 'SATURDAY') AS last_saturday,
       NEXT_DAY(sysdate-7, 'SUNDAY') AS last_sunday
from dual;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following PLSQL Function to get the DayDate of Week.

Usage of function to get Day of Month.

```sql
SELECT
 DayofMonth(to_date('2020-03-29T01:00Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'FRI', 'LAST') LASTFRI    -- 27-MAR-2020 01:00:00
 ,DayofMonth(to_date('2020-03-29T01:00Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'SUN', 'FIRST') FIRSTSUN -- 01-MAR-2020 01:00:00
 ,DayofMonth(to_date('2020-03-29T01:00Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'SUN', 'THIRD') THIRDSUN -- 15-MAR-2020 01:00:00
 
 ,DayofMonth(to_date('2020-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'SUN', 'THIRD') THIRDSUN_FEB29  -- 16-FEB-2020 01:01:00
 ,DayofMonth(to_date('2021-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'SUN', 'FOURTH') FouthSUN_FEB28 -- 28-FEB-2021 01:01:00
from dual;
```

PLSQL-Function: Below function which identifies the Last Day of the Month, Converts to Number using [`TO_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions211.htm?_sm_au_=iVVM5Vr8THV8002qM4728KHvT1cjF#SQLRF06140) function to pass as a parameter to [`LAST_DAY()`](https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/datetime-functions/oracle-last_day-function.php) function.

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION DayofMonth 
(dateOfMonth in date, dayOfWeek in varchar2 default 'SUN', weekOfMonth in varchar2 default 'LAST')
return date AS date_out date;

firstDayOfMonth number(5); lastDayOfMonth number(5);
monthFirstDayDate date; monthSecondDayDate date;
monthThirdDayDate date; monthFourthDayDate date;
monthLastDayDate date;
BEGIN

  SELECT TO_NUMBER(to_char( trunc(dateOfMonth) - (to_number(to_char(dateOfMonth,'DD')) - 1), 'DD'), '9G999D99') into firstDayOfMonth FROM dual;
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(to_char(trunc( add_months(trunc(dateOfMonth) - (to_number(to_char(dateOfMonth,'DD')) - 1), 1) -1 ), 'DD'), '9G999D99') into lastDayOfMonth FROM dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('firstDayOfMonth:' || firstDayOfMonth || ', lastDayOfMonth:' || lastDayOfMonth);

select next_day(LAST_DAY(dateOfMonth) - (lastDayOfMonth - (7 * 0)), dayOfWeek) into monthFirstDayDate   FROM DUAL;
select next_day(LAST_DAY(dateOfMonth) - (lastDayOfMonth - (7 * 1)), dayOfWeek) into monthSecondDayDate  FROM DUAL;
select next_day(LAST_DAY(dateOfMonth) - (lastDayOfMonth - (7 * 2)), dayOfWeek) into monthThirdDayDate   FROM DUAL;
select next_day(LAST_DAY(dateOfMonth) - (lastDayOfMonth - (7 * 3)), dayOfWeek) into monthFourthDayDate  FROM DUAL;
select next_day(LAST_DAY(dateOfMonth) - (7),                        dayOfWeek) into monthLastDayDate    FROM DUAL;

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('monthFirstDayDate:'  || monthFirstDayDate || ', monthSecondDayDate:' || monthSecondDayDate);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('monthThirdDayDate:'  || monthThirdDayDate || ', monthFourthDayDate:' || monthFourthDayDate);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('monthLastDayDate:'   || monthLastDayDate);

IF (weekOfMonth = 'LAST') then
  date_out := monthLastDayDate;
ELSIF (weekOfMonth = 'FIRST') then
  date_out := monthFirstDayDate;
ELSIF (weekOfMonth = 'SECOND') then
  date_out := monthSecondDayDate;
ELSIF (weekOfMonth = 'THIRD') then
  date_out := monthThirdDayDate;
ELSIF (weekOfMonth = 'FOURTH') then
  date_out := monthFourthDayDate;
ELSE
  date_out := null;
END IF;

    return date_out;
EXCEPTION
    when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Date:' || dateOfMonth || ', Day:' || dayOfWeek || ', Week:' || weekOfMonth || ' / ' || sqlcode || ' / ' || SQLERRM(sqlcode));
        date_out := null;
        return date_out;
END;
/
```

---

First and Last Day of Month - [Oracle SQL](https://www.mandsconsulting.com/first-and-last-day-of-month-oracle-sql-syntax-examples/)

```sql
SELECT
  to_char( trunc(sysdate) - (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD')) - 1), 'DD') as firstDay
  ,to_char(trunc( add_months(trunc(sysdate) - (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD')) - 1), 1) -1 ), 'DD') as lastDay
FROM dual;
```

Tests to check the Day of the Month with out any function:

```sql
select
    next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-01-29T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - 7, 'sun') as JAN_Month_Last_SUNDAY31 -- 31-JAN-2021 01:01:00
    ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-02-01T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - 7, 'sun') as FEB_Month_Last_SUNDAY28 -- 28-FEB-2021 01:01:00
    ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-04-01T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - 7, 'sun') as APRL_Month_Last_SUNDAY30 -- 25-APR-2021 01:01:00
    
    ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-01-29T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - 31, 'sun') as JAN_Month_First_SUNDAY31 -- 31-JAN-2021 01:01:00
    ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-02-01T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - 28, 'sun') as FEB_Month_First_SUNDAY28 -- 28-FEB-2021 01:01:00
    ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-04-01T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - 30, 'sun') as APRL_Month_First_SUNDAY30 -- 25-APR-2021 01:01:00
FROM DUAL;

select
  next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-01-29T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - 7, 'mon') as JAN_Month_Last_Mon31
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-01-29T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - 7, 'fri') as JAN_Month_Last_Fri31
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-01-29T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (31 - (7 * 0)), 'fri') as JAN_Month_First_Fri31
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-01-29T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (31 - (7 * 1)), 'fri') as JAN_Month_Second_Fri31
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-01-29T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (31 - (7 * 2)), 'fri') as JAN_Month_Third_Fri31
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-01-29T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (31 - (7 * 3)), 'fri') as JAN_Month_Fourth_Fri31
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-01-29T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (31), 'fri') as JAN_Month_Last_Fri31
FROM DUAL;

select
  next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (28 - (7 * 0)), 'fri') as FEB_Month_First_Fri28
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (28 - (7 * 1)), 'fri') as FEB_Month_Second_Fri28
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (28 - (7 * 2)), 'fri') as FEB_Month_Third_Fri28
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (28 - (7 * 3)), 'SUN') as FEB_Month_Fourth_Fri28
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2021-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (7), 'fri') as FEB_Month_Last_Fri28
FROM DUAL;

select
  next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2020-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (29 - (7 * 0)), 'fri') as FEB_Month_First_Fri29
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2020-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (29 - (7 * 1)), 'fri') as FEB_Month_Second_Fri29
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2020-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (29 - (7 * 2)), 'fri') as FEB_Month_Third_Fri29
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2020-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (29 - (7 * 3)), 'fri') as FEB_Month_Fourth_Fri29
  ,next_day(LAST_DAY(to_date('2020-02-02T01:01Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"')) - (7), 'fri') as FEB_Month_Last_Fri29
FROM DUAL;
```